# node.js server is running but won't serve the requests

Tags: node.js, server, http-status-code-502

My app hosted on ec2 t2.micro instance was unreachable and was showing 504 gateway time-out, I rebooted the instance and now I could login to the server.

I restarted my app.js file using pm2 it showed me the app is listening on port 80. But when I searched on the browser, it showed me 502 Bad Gateway.

Then instead of pm2 i directly launched app by using `node app.js` . Still showing same error.

Things to note:

1. I checked with netstat port 80 is open.
2. I checked mongod service is also in running status.
3. Disk space is not full, there is plenty left.
4. Instead of putting domain name(bought from godaddy) i did put
   public dns and public IP of my ec2 server on the browser they showed
   site refused to connect.
5. All inbound and outbound rules are correct.
6. pm2 is also showing that app is running.

Is it possible that after reboot something got deleted or changed to some inappropriate configuration?
And what can be some other reasons causing this?

Comment: Can you check your DNS settings?
It might be faulty

Comment: I have checked the DNS settings, only the Load balancer is showing 502 bad gateway,
if I access using IP address then the site loads normally.